# Compare document array size to other document field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The document might look like:

```
{
  _id: 'abc',
  programId: 'xyz',
  enrollment: 'open',
  people: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  maxPeople: 5
}
```

I need to return all documents where enrollment is `open` and the length of `people` is less than `maxPeople`

I got this to work with `$where`:

```
const
  exists = ['enrollment', 'maxPeople', 'people'],
  query = _.reduce(exists, (existsQuery, field) => {
    existsQuery[field] = {'$exists': true}; return existsQuery; 
  }, {});

query['$and'] = [{enrollment: 'open'}];
query['$where'] = 'this.people.length<this.maxPeople';
return db.coll.find(query, {fields: {programId: 1, maxPeople: 1, people: 1}});
```

But could I do this with aggregation, and why would it be better?

Also, if aggregation is better/faster, I don't understand how I could convert the above query to use aggregation. I'm stuck at:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$project: {ab: {$cmp: ['$maxPeople','$someHowComputePeopleLength']}}},
  {$match: {ab:{$gt:0}}}
]);
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on @chridam answer, I was able to implement a solution like so, note the `$and` in the `$match`, for those of you that need a similar query:

```
  return Coll.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $and: [
          {"enrollment": "open"},
          {"times.start.dateTime": {$gte: new Date()}}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
          {"$lt": [{"$size": "$students" }, "$maxStudents" ] },
          "$$KEEP",
          "$$PRUNE"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator in the aggregation framework should work for you in this case. This will recursively descend through the document structure and do some actions based on an evaluation of specified conditions at each level. The concept can be a bit tricky to grasp but basically the operator allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which restricts contents of the result set based on the access required to view the data and is more efficient.

---

To run a query on all documents where `enrollment` is open and the length of `people` is less than `maxPeople`, include a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** stage as in the following::

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "enrollment": "open" } },
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$lt": [ { "$size": "$people" }, "$maxPeople" ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

- 1 `$project` that create a new field featuring the result of the comparison for the array size of `people` to `maxPeople`
- 1 `$match` that match the previous comparison result & `enrollment` to `open`

Query is :

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        programId: 1,
        enrollment: 1,
        cmp: {
            $cmp: ["$maxPeople", { $size: "$people" }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { cmp: { $gt: 0 } },
            { enrollment: "open" }
        ]
    }
}])
```

Comment: While approach will work, as @chridam pointed out, "$redact uses a single pipeline stage which restricts contents of the result set based on the access required to view the data and is more efficient."